# C++ Hangman Visual

Tags: c++, codeblocks, openframeworks

Hello I have to design a game in CodeBlocks using Openframeworks and I thought hangman would be a simple yet challenging (for me) game to design. The Openframework is going to to draw a face, arm, legs, etc, whenever the user types in the wrong letter.

However I am wondering if it would be possible to have the "_ _ _ _ *" inside of Openframeworks and then start displaying the letters as they get it right, "* a _ _ _ s". Is there a function that lets me print letters in certain location or how could I go on about this? Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome here. Do you have tried anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do some research before posting a question right away.

> [ofTrueTypeFont](http://openframeworks.cc/documentation/graphics/ofTrueTypeFont.html)